# what kind of tree is this in central Florida?

Tags: identification, trees, transplanting, roots, thorns

[image]

Tree with dark green leaves on the right, not the pine on the left.

in very sandy soil. wondering if will be difficult to transplant? does it have thorns? deep hard roots? What time of year good time to transplant.  Should i trim it first and give it time to remover.. cut around roots and then get under it?

Almost looks like an orange tree.

Comment: can you post a closeup of the leaf and bark?

Comment: Not on the lot for another 2 weeks.  photo zoom is possible. Maybe it's an oak?

Comment: It's hard to answer this. Tree on the right or the left? Why do you want to transplant it?

Comment: tree on right.  in way of site plan